# How to delete files from a directory based on the contents of a gzipped tar file?

Tags: centos, pipe, tar, command, gzip

Given that I:

- have a directory that contains over 1000 files
- have a gzip'ed tar file that contains a subset of those files (x.tgz)

What is the single command line (if it is possible) that will read the gzip'ed tar file's contents and removes all of the files from the directory that are contained within the tar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to be at the directory from which the tar file was created, for instance `$HOME`. Then if you had a tgz of your Documents directory located safely in `/backup/Documents.tgz` you would do this:

```
$ for file in $(tar -tzf /backup/Documents.tgz); do \
      [[ -f $file ]] && rm $file || echo "$file does not exist"; done
```

If you want to also delete directories you would use `rm -fr $file`.

Comment: This does not work if you have symlinks in the archive.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this will help you

```
rm -rf `find . -name '*.tgz' -exec tar -tzf '{}' \;`
```

not sure how it will work with so many files.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ tar -tzf x.tgz  |grep -v '/$' | xargs -n1 -d '\n' echo rm
```

Remove the `echo` if it looks good.

Explanation:

- `tar -tzf x.tgz`  -- list the contents
- `grep -v '/$'` -- skip directories
- `xargs -n1 -d '\n' echo rm` -- for each one (`-n1`) line (`-d '\n'`) of input, run `echo rm`

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer: this does not work if there are symlinks in the archive.

Answer (score 0):

As tar (even in non-verbose mode) lists symlinks and hardlinks in the `tar t` output, you cannot use `tar t` to get the list if files. Better use:

`star -t -tpath < archive.tar > file-list.txt`